# RESTful API for Cosmos map-reduce

Tags: fiware

I' m working with the FIWARE BigData Analysis GE - Cosmos, and I need to use RESTful APIs.
I know that there are RESTful APIs for HDFS (e.g. WebHDFS), but may I run MapReduce jobs? How?

Thanks

Comment: The key tech. here is ETL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/apache-hadoop-etl-at-scale#:~:text=Extract%2C%20transform%2C%20and%20load%20(ETL)%20is%20the%20process,is%20acquired%20from%20various%20sources.&text=Legacy%20ETL%20processes%20import%20data,components%20support%20ETL%20at%20scale.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a REST API for running MapReduce jobs, but there is an [Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) server running on the instance of Cosmos in FIWARE LAB addressing this issue.

By using Oozie you can describe workflows of data analysis; you can see these workflows as a sequence of actions executed to process data, being these actions MapReduce jobs, Hive queries, shell scripts, etc.

Thus, you can describe a single action workflow for a MapReduce job.

Oozie can be used in [several ways](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide#Programming_an_Oozie_application), one of them is through its REST API. All the details can be found [here](http://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/BigData_Analysis_-_User_and_Programmer_Guide#API_REST).